# Delete Product Custom Option value if it is null in magento 2

Tags: product, custom-options, magento-2.2.5, delete

I wish to delete the custom options value of a product if it is null  without deleting the option.

Please provide me a solution to delete it without affecting the option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using below function you can **delete the custom options values**. Here I **compared the value title as NULL** and delete the custom options values

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = 2057;
$productRepository = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$this->prodOptionValue = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\Value');
$product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
if (!empty($product->getOptions())) {
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
        foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) {
            if($value->getTitle() == NULL){
                $this->prodOptionValue->deleteValues($value->getOptionTypeId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Instead of using objectManager, try to use the ProductRepositoryInterface,Value (modal) in the constructor